# Rails 5.0.2 Deployment on Digital Ocean Passenger issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger, web-deployment

I am currently deploying a test rails 5.0 app to digital ocean following this tutorial:

> https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

My code is as-is in the tutorial and yet when deploying using capistrano, I get the following log on passenger:restart.

```
There are no Phusion Passenger-served applications running whose paths begin with '/home/deploy/app_name''.
```

The net effect is that ip still shows me the Nginx welcome page.

All input welcome. Thanks!

Edit:

```
00:56 passenger:restart
  01 passenger-config restart-app /home/deploy/app_name --ignore-app-not-running
  01 There are no Phusion Passenger-served applications running whose paths begin with '/home/deploy/app_name'.
```

Edit 2 `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name mydomain.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/deploy/my_app_name/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of the `/home/deploy/app_name` directory?

Comment: They are: current releases repo revisions.log shared Thanks!

Comment: You need to change your nginx `root` directive to: `/home/deploy/app_name/current/public`

Comment: It's already set in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  app_name.com;


  root /mnt/apps/app_name/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.0;

  proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  add_header              Front-End-Https   on;


  if ($request_method !~ "^(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT|DELETE|PATCH)$"){
    return 403;
  }

  rewrite /favicon.ico$ /favicon.ico break;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I switched my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` from the original (2nd edit) to yours. Running `sudo nginx -t` said I needed passenger entreprise to make passenger_min_instances and max_instances work so I removed them. Runnong `sudo nginx -t` everything is ok but visiting the IP address the website is down. Apologies it's first time deploying

Comment: @Ender what error message do you get when you visit the page? I believe you would have to type the hostname that maps to the IP address.

Comment: Unable to connect. Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ip address. I still get the same error with your edit, quick note I adapted the `passenger_ruby` line to point to rvm since that's what I have in the `passenger.conf` file

Comment: @Ender sounds like you have some firewall rules preventing access are running on Linux ?  did you check iptables?

Comment: I am running ubuntu, I haven't touched the firewall yet. I ended up deleting the droplet to retry tonight

Comment: any tips on tracing it to something concrete, I get the same "error" when I use the one-click rails ? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: @Ender did you fix the problem ?

Comment: Sorry haven't been here in a min, no I didn't even w extra help. So I deployed the store as a wordpress site :|